# Is there any way to customize the color of text on an axis on an svg element?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Hi I'm new to d3 and html and all the rest, I am trying to building a simple bar chart but I would like to customize the color of the category that appears on the x-axis, that is I want for each category to have its own color, much like each bar has its own color. I am able to change the of he text like this

```
        this.xAxis.style({
            "font-size": d3.min([height, width]) * BarChart.Config.xAxisFontMultiplier,
            "fill": settings.enableAxis.fill,
        });
```

but is there any way to do per label? I saw something about creating a tspan property but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to an axis in this manner.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After drawing the axis you have to find all the text elements of the xAxis and set the `fill` based on the text of the label.

```
d3.select(".axis--x").selectAll("text")
    .attr('fill', d => color(d) );
```

`color` is the function mapping key to color. The function you use to color the bars.

Comment: You are a boss! Thank you so much. I'll just clarify for others because it took me some time to understand the syntax of the selection is the class name of the axis, preceded by its class type. By me it was created using 

this.xAxis = this.svg
                .append('g')
                .classed('xAxis', true);
so the appropriate select argument was "g.xAxis"

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class name to your axis and select the `text` svg element inside it to apply your color rule:

```
JS:
svgSelection
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'chart-labels')
    .call(yAxis);

 CSS:
.chart-labels text {
    color: red
}
```